# How to open html file in intellij directly?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, shortcut

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIyGQ.png)
Hi! I can open html file in intellij following image. But I wanna open it directly for short cut command.I found a shortcut list that intellij offered. But I couldn't find it. How do I this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preview a HTML file you are editing in IDEA in a browser press Alt+F2 (cmd+F2 on Mac) - it should give you a pop-up window, where you just have to click the name of the browser you want to run.

More on HTML/XML previews in the [IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editing-html-files.html#ws_html_preview_output_built_in_browser).